# Order by doing an inner join automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I want my query, using hql, return some values ordered by some columns.

The problem is when I `order by` it automatically does a inner join.
Example:

Table Usuario has column idAssociado:

```
select u.nome 
from Usuario u
order by u.associado desc,
         u.associado.suspended asc, 
         u.associado.dateOut asc
```

I want to return all records from Usuario even when column associado(id) is null, but bringing first those who is not null then ordered by suspended and dateOut.

When I `order by suspended and dateOut` it does an inner join and returns only Usuarios `where u.associado is not null`.

How can I perform this hql with expected results?

Thanks

Comment: if `u.associado` is a valid reference to a column, then `u.associado.suspended` and `u.associado.dateOut` cannot also be valid references.

Comment: Ok, I understand what's going on, but i dont know how to archive the expected results given this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`HQL` does an `INNER JOIN` operation if your property in your class is in a POJO object.

In your `Usuario` class you have, probably, a property `associado` with type `Associado`.

So when you point an encapsuled property of associado object HQL apply an INNER JOIN.

If you want all usuario objects when associado is null, why you order by your information about encapsuled information in associado?

For me, you query will become:

```
select u.nome 
from Usuario u
where u.associado is null
```

Comment: I want those who is not null also... bu anyway... how, starting from your sktrech, i can return data ordered by u.associado.suspended and u.associado.dateOut? My point is when you use these itens to order, it automatically remove non null values... i understand why, but how to resolve it?